# R Programming - How to convert a data from sqlite to datetime

Tags: r, sqlite

I have queried a data from sqlite file that is a datetime stamp, & I want to view that in RStudio as a datetime .

```
p3 = dbGetQuery(DB, 'select * from TagReadInstance')
print(p3)
p4 <- p3
p5 <- p4[,"LastSeen"]
print(p5)
```

Output of p5 is as below :

```
p5 <- p4[,"LastSeen"]
> print(p5)
integer64
[1] -8586484961621558032 -8586484961494286032
```

How can I convert the output to datetime?

Comment: What sort of time format does that number represent? It doesn't look like Unix time or any other format suggested for use with sqlite.

Comment: Saves the system date and time